# Is there a statistical term for ratio of average for user to average of all users?

Tags: terminology, standardization, ratio

I am working on an email application. To determine if an email is important one of the features we are considering is a `ratio of avg time to open an email from a particular contact` to `avg time to open an email from all the contacts`. I was just curious to know if there a *statistical* term for this kind of ratio? Is it just a 'ratio of averages'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any specific term in statistics for this. I would give it an informative name based on the specifics of the problem, such as 'email response time ratio', and then define it for the audience.